# Why text I/O must be buffered in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

Python 2 supported unbuffered text I/O.

The same approach doesn't work in python 3. Why was unbuffered text I/O disabled?

```
> import sys
> sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
builtins.ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O
```

The binary still works fine:

```
> sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', 0) # works fine
```

Comment: At least for reading, I suspect that it has something to do with text being unicode, so that byte != char.  If the underlying bytes stream is utf-8 encoded, a single char is a variable number of bytes, so there must be a buffer to contain left-over bytes after complete chars are read.  I presume there was a pep for the new io module (and sys.stdout above is probably an IO class instance).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is an open bug, issue # 17404 (last update 2013-03-13): http://bugs.python.org/issue17404

Comment: In 3.7.2, unbuffered text I/O is not supported. See: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/61606#issuecomment-1093610383

Answer (score 9):

For text files, if you want to use the buffering line-by-line, use `open(..., buffering=1)`

From python documentation:

> 1 to select line buffering (only usable in text mode)