# Python: contextlib.redirect_stdout sometimes doesn't work in real time

Tags: python, io-redirection, buffering

I am using Python3.5 on Ubuntu. The following script creates a file `out` and fills it with more and more lines of "Hello":

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(open('out','w')):
    while True:
        print('Hello')
```

However, if I make a tiny modification by adding a call to `time.sleep()`, the file `out` stays empty:

```
import contextlib
import time
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(open('out','w')):
    while True:
        print('Hello')
        time.sleep(1)
```

If I further change the code by turning the loop into a finite loop, it fills `out` but only in a lump at the end of the loop.

Can anyone reproduce this and explain it?

Comment: Great question. Just in case someone else comes here for a similar issue, from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout): "It also has no effect on the output of subprocesses. However, it is still a useful approach for many utility scripts".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by output buffering. This is an interesting case given the use of `contextlib`, but the underlying issue is with the `open('out', 'w')` statement.

To prevent output buffering, you can set the [buffering argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) to `0` if you're using Python 2:

```
import contextlib
import time

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(open('out','w', 0)):
    while True:
        print 'Hello'
        time.sleep(1)
```

Alternatively, the file contents will be written once the context manager closes the file (or once the buffered content exceeds a certain size).

If you're using Python 3, then you can't have unbuffered text I/O (kindly pointed out in the comments). However, flushing `stdout` at the end of each loop should have the desired effect:

```
import contextlib
import time
import sys

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(open('out','w')):
    while True:
        print('Hello')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in Python3, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067713/why-text-i-o-must-be-buffered-in-python-3

Comment: Good catch, sorry I should have tested my answer properly. Updated to give a suitable workaround for Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

I bet this has been asked before but I can't find a good duplicate.

This is caused by output buffering. When stdout goes to a terminal, it is line buffered, meaning output is sent from your program to the terminal every time a `"\n"` is encountered. But when stdout refers to a file, it is block buffered. This means actual output is generated only when the buffer grows full (or when you explicitly flush it or when the handle is closed).